# Ajax success method not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2 MVC and I have a Controller with a Post action method as such:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostObject([FromForm] ObjectViewModel bjectViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
    //EF code
    return Ok(object);
}
```

My view has the following code:

```
//View code...
<form asp-action="PostObject" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="OnSuccess" data-ajax-failure="OnFailure">
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.VolumeID)
    <label asp-for="EAN" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="EAN" id="TextBoxEAN" class="form-control" value="" maxlength="13" autofocus />
    <span asp-validation-for="EAN" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
//More view code...

//This contais ajax stuff
@section Scripts {@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script>
function OnSuccess(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
function OnFailure(result) {
    alert(result);
}
</script>
```

I can perform the POST action correctly, but instead of executing the OnSuccess method, it just displays the returned JSON object.

I think this has something to do with referencing ajax-unobtrusive, but I think that is taken care of automatically.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you included `jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax.js` (its not done automatically).

Comment: And I would recommend you just use the `$.ajax()` methods rather that the `jquery.ubobtrusive-ajax.js` which is no longer supported and not recommended by the MVC team

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, is there anywhere I can read about that in detail?

Comment: Do you mean using `$.ajax()`? - if so, start with the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)